# Script to import data from csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, csv

I have a script that is supposed to import data from .csv into mysql database tables.

The script should read a a config file that maps the importing process, for example if the config file looks like this:

```
1 A
2 B
3 D
```

A, B and D are columns names in the mysql table.

Then the bash script will import 1, 2, 3 from the .csv to A, B and D respectively.

How can I first check if there are no repetitions of column names (no more than one B for example), and what approach should I take to make this process work.

Comment: While reading each row and extracting the column name you can "grep --count" against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this script:

```
var1=`cat filename|awk {'print $2'}|uniq -u|wc -l`
var2=`cat filename|awk {'print $2'}|wc -l`
if [ $var1 -eq $var2 ]; 
then
#run script
else 
echo 'Same column present more than once'
fi
```